# Damsel In reCaptcha Distress. Please Help?

Tags: recaptcha

For 9 months, I've been having reCaptcha problems. Craigslist is the main problem. It sometimes happens in Hotmail too. Anytime I go to post or respond to a CL ad that requires Image Verification (recaptcha), neither the challenge words or the box to type the words into pops up. Refreshing does not help. Hitting "new image" or "audio words" does nothing.

I end up forfeiting placing or responding to certain ads. As you might imagine, CL's Help Forums has amounted to no answers whatsoever. Some suggested I go to Google reCaptcha links. That did not help because anything Google-related was blocked even though in the Toolbar Google was activated. Both posters and staff alike venture all manner of solutions, none of which actually helped. It's mainly guesswork.

Many told me it was a scripting error and to disable javascript. Others claimed it was Norton (somehow) blocking any sites using reCaptcha. Norton comes with my Comcast X-Finity account. I could be wrong but I didn't see anything specific in Norton that might be blocking reCaptcha imaging. One person even swore it's a simple as fully rebooting the modem. Nope. Another said try another browser. I downloaded Mozilla Firefox. Firefox works great for everything but reCaptcha. I've even went to other tech sites. Again, no answers. 9 months and not one person or site can tell me how come CL's reCaptcha image words challenge won't pop up or how to fix it. If fixing it involves typing in code, I have no idea how to do that.

Surely there must be a fix for this as reCaptcha isn't rocket science. As specific as I've been seeking help, you'd think there'd be a solution?

Would someone kindly help?

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: @PaulR: Belongs nowhere on SE.

Answer (score 3):

"That did not help because anything Google-related was blocked" -- there's your problem. reCAPTCHA served from Google servers, so if you can't access anything Google-related, you can't access reCAPTCHA.